# How can I create a git alias to delete a tag remotely?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-alias

I'm having trouble creating a git alias to delete a tag remotely.

I have the following in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  deltag = push origin :refs/tags/$1
```

Running the `deltag` alias after deleting a tag locally (with `git tag -d testtag`) results in this error:

```
$ git deltag testtag
error: src refspec testtag does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://........'
```

Attempting to run this alias *before* deleting it locally results in this instead:

```
$ git deltag testtag
remote: warning: Deleting a non-existent ref.
To ssh://........
- [deleted]         $1
```

What is the correct syntax to use for this alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by hunting around on StackOverflow and putting some other answers together.

There may be other solutions too, but turning the alias into a **shell command** successfully passes the tag argument through:

```
[alias]
  deltag = !sh -c 'git push origin :refs/tags/$1' -
```

Or even better, combining both the local and remote delete into one alias:

```
[alias]
  deltag = !sh -c 'git tag -d $1 && git push origin :refs/tags/$1' -
```

The output:

```
$ git deltag testtag
Deleted tag 'testtag' (was be73a23)
To ssh://.......
 - [deleted]         testtag
```

Comment: Pleas use full refspec as `refs/tags/$1`, otherwise branch with the same name could be deleted

Comment: @MaxK Thank you for this Max!